# python beautiful soup output into excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the output from the python script into excel. The script works fine in Python, but when I try and do the import CSV and writerow rule it doesn't work. It says price not defined in writerow and how would I print multiple items. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('dataoutput.csv','w', newline = "")
writer = csv.writer(f)

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/property/manchester/?identifier=manchester&q=manchester&search_source=home&radius=0&pn=' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'listing-results-price text-price'}):
            href = "http://www.zoopla.co.uk" + link.get('href')
            title = link.string 
            get_single_item_data(href) 
        page +=1

def get_single_item_data(item_url): 
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for item_name in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'listing-details-address'}):
     address = item_name.string
     print(item_name.get_text(strip=True))
    for item_fame in soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'listing-details-price text-price'}):
        price = item_fame.string 
        print(item_fame.get_text(strip=True))

writer.writerow(price)

trade_spider(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The object `price` is not defined anywhere in your script outside of the function `get_single_item_data`. Outside of that function your code cannot recognize any object with that name. Also, `get_single_item_data` does not return anything from the BeautifulSoup object. It only prints it. You should rewrite your function to be something like this:

```
def get_single_item_data(item_url): 
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

    #create list to contain addresses
    addresses = []

    for item_name in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'listing-details-address'}):
        address = item_name.string

        #add each address to the list
        addresses.append(address)

        print(item_name.get_text(strip=True))

    #create list for prices
    prices = []

    for item_fame in soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'listing-details-price text-price'}):
        price = item_fame.string 

        #add prices to list
        prices.append(price)

        print(item_fame.get_text(strip=True))

  #alter the code to return the data structure you prefer.
  return([addresses,prices])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to python and must be doing something wrond, I tried the above and it says return is outside function

Comment: This error means you need to put the return statement inside the function. in python this probably means you need to hit tab one more time so that it is indented once more than the `def` line.